# Responsive table in iframe not working on iPhone but work on other device

Tags: iphone, iframe, responsive-design, responsive, jquery-jtable

[http://declanbright.awardspace.info/jquery-plugin-responsive-table](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables)

I use this plugin for my table. 
but I put my table in an `iframe` then it's not working on  `iphone`, 
but work on the other devices

I've already add the code↓

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

How can I solve this problem? 
Or is there some incompatible between iOS device and iframe?

Answer (score 0):

try add this style to the container div of the page which included on the iframe.

```
width: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    *width: 100%;
```